# A phrase similar to "It's what you do that makes you who you are"

Tags: phrase-requests

I remembered this really corny phrase today when I was on a walk but I forgot later before I could write it down.

It's kind of like "You are what you eat" but with different words.

It's not:

> You reap what you sow.

> You're the sum of your actions.

> Easier said than done. 
> (It is a different one but they're both about contiguity. I don't remember what it is.)

Comment: Biblical, perhaps? By your fruits shall ye be known?

Comment: thats close but is like simple english or something

Comment: Could you please write the title and question more comprehensibly? It is rather difficult to understand.

Comment: It's either *Actions speak louder than words* or it isn't. You show what you don't want, and not what you do want. Is it contiguity, not integrity?

Comment: The clothes make the man?

Comment: Suggestion.  Learn the difference between *its* and *it's*

Comment: Not sure exactly what meaning you want. *Actions speak louder than words*, *Existence precedes essence*, or somewhere inbetween that?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpPeQyT36Tg

Comment: I believe the simple English version of what Xanne said is "[a tree is known by its fruit.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tree+is+known+by+its+fruit)"

Comment: It's more than a phrase, but I'm reminded of this quote attributed to Lao Tzu:  “Watch your thoughts, they become your words; watch your words, they become your actions; watch your actions, they become your habits; watch your habits, they become your character; watch your character, it becomes your destiny.”

Comment: "Fake it till you make it"?

Comment: @Xanne I was thinking along the same lines, but in reverse: ‘Clothes _don’t_ make the man’ would fit, since ‘clothes make the man’ means quite the opposite, that outward appearance makes people think they know what we are (≈ judging the book by its cover), rather than looking to our actions or personality.

Comment: The Velvet Underground's song *I Found a Reason* has lyrics which read, "Oh, I do believe. You are what you perceive and what comes is better than what came before." https://genius.com/The-velvet-underground-i-found-a-reason-lyrics

Answer (score 8):

Carl Gustav Jung said

> ***You are what you do***, not what you say you’ll do. ([dailyinspirationalquotes](https://www.dailyinspirationalquotes.in/2019/09/you-are-what-you-do-not-what-you-say-youll-do-carl-gustav-jung/))

> ***Your actions define you***

or

> ***What you do is who you are***

can also be used.

There is even a book with this title: *[What you do is who you are](https://www.waterstones.com/book/what-you-do-is-who-you-are/ben-horowitz/9780008356118)*.

Answer (score 6):

**Handsome is as handsome does.**

> *handsome is as handsome does*
>
> Actions, not appearances, are what count [what define a person]. This
> proverb was already an “ancient adage” in 1580 (Anthony Monday, Sunday
> Examples) when it was put as “goodly is he that goodly dooth”; it
> appeared in modern form in John Ray’s proverbs of 1670 and has been
> repeated over and over by numerous writers.

[[The Dictionary of Clichés by Christine Ammer](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/handsome+is+as+handsome+does)]

> *handsome is as handsome does*
>
> Proverbial saying, late 16th century; handsome here originally
> referred to chivalrous or genteel behaviour, although it is often
> popularly taken to refer to good looks.

[[Oxford Reference](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/oi/authority.20110810105037422;jsessionid=389DC58B9C81EAF3AC888266F78CD82A)]

Answer (score 4):

> Actions speak louder than words

Comment: It's not a bad suggestion but could do with some supporting examples.

Answer (score 3):

### We are what we repeatedly do.

This is often attributed to Aristotle, but it is from Will Durrant.  Durrant's fuller expression was:

> ...we are what we repeatedly do. Excellence, then, is not an act but a habit.

Durrant was commenting on what Aristotle [actually wrote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Aristotle#Misattributed):

> ...these virtues are formed in man by his doing the actions

Answer (score 3):

One somewhat similar phrase is: **"A tree is known by its fruit."** [TFD defines it as:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tree+is+known+by+its+fruit)

> A person's or group's character or worth is determined by others based on their actions or the results thereof.

This proverbial expression comes from the Bible (Matthew 7:16).

Answer (score 2):

- You are your actions.

This is the plain rendering in words of the idea found in the description, and someone has thought worthwhile to use it as the theme of an essai and as part of the title of it. ([You are not your thoughts. You are your actions](https://www.reddit.com/r/selfimprovement/comments/lj0t3z/you_are_not_your_thoughts_you_are_your_actions/))

Answer (score 2):

While less terse than other answers and certainly not a stock phrase, this line from *Batman Begins* expresses your intended meaning with an impactful edge.

> It's not who I am underneath, but what I *do* that defines me.

You could rephrase to third person for a generalisation.

> It's not who you are underneath, but what you *do* that defines you.

Comment: It sounds marvellous (sorry, wrong franchise), but surely 'what one is deep down' and 'what one does' are inextricably connected. It's 'how one often appears [on the surface]' that may be at odds with actuality.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be "**Manners maketh man**"?

This means "you are the sum of how you act".  It is attributed to William of Wykeham (1324–1404) according to Oxford Reference (https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100131244).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From Forest Gump, one of the popular lines is:

> [Stupid is as stupid does](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tldGgGFe194)

Searching the meaning of the phrase [suggests](https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=91c2ce7b-6c79-4163-86ab-6690080e6383) that the meaning is widely believed to be that appearance doesn't define you, but what you do.

Answer (score 0):

**What you do speaks so loudly that I cannot hear what you say.**

Attributed to [Ralph Waldo Emerson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Waldo_Emerson). It has many alternative formulations:

> Don’t say things. What you are stands over you the while, and thunders so that I cannot hear what you say to the contrary.
>
> Don’t talk. What you are thunders so loudly above what you say that I cannot hear you.
>
> Be still, for what you are stands over you and speaks so loudly I cannot hear what you say.
>
> What you are stands over you and thunders, and denies what you say.
>
> What you are, thunders so loud that I cannot hear what you say.
>
> What you are speaks so loud I can not hear what you say
>
> What you do speaks so loud, that I cannot hear what you say.

https://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/01/27/what-you-do-speaks/

https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/486985-your-actions-speak-so-loudly-i-can-not-hear-what

Answer (score 0):

Character is destiny.

(from Heraclitus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraclitus)

Answer (score 0):

"Existence precedes essence" or *"l'existence précède l'essence"* in the original French is a phrase that comes out of Existentialism and means more-or-less what you're looking for, though with strong philosophical overtones.

It was first published in Sartre's 1946 work "Existentialism Is a Humanism."

[plato.stanford.edu](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/existentialism/) provides an explanation of the phrase (bolding own):

> *Existence Precedes Essence:* Existentialists forward a novel conception of the self not as a substance or thing with some pre-given nature (or “essence”) but as a situated activity or way of being whereby we are always in the process of making or creating who we are as our life unfolds. This means our essence is not given in advance; **we are contingently thrown into existence and are burdened with the task of creating ourselves through our choices and actions.**